# Reuse patterns in awk program

Tags: awk

I want to write a somehow long awk program and therefore make my code more readable and easier to maintain. The first code snippet works but it is hard to read and harder to maintain.

```
/\(..-av-es\/.*\)/ {
    split($0, arr, /\(..-av-es\/.*\)/)
}
```

Therefore I would like to define the regex once inside the variable and use the variable.
`$0 ~ PATTERN {...}` works but  `split($0, arr, PATTERN)` doesn't. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
BEGIN { PATTERN="\(..-av-es\/.*\)"}

$0 ~ PATTERN {
    split($0, arr, PATTERN)

}
```

EDIT:
I have a file structured like this.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
abc (fd-av-es/key1) value1sdfsdaff
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
(sd-av-es/key2) value2sdfsdaff
```

my final goal is having an array of strings `"key1:value1"`  `"key2:value2"`

This snippet

```
/\(..-av-es\/.*\)/ {
    split($0, arr, /\(..-av-es\/.*\)/)
    for ( i in arr) {print NR arr[i]}
}
```

returns which brings me a little closer to value1 and value2

```
2abc
2 value1afjskhslakjhf
4
4 value2jkalshfkjkl
```

but

```
BEGIN { PATTERN="\(..-av-es\/.*\)"}
$0 ~ ES_PATTERN {
    split($0, arr, ES_PATTERN)
    for ( i in arr) {print NR arr[i]}
}
```

however returns:

```
2abc (
2
4(
4
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You'll probably need to double the backslashes in the quoted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have in your question is a regexp so call them that instead of the highly ambiguous "patterns". See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info on that topic.

You don't need to provide the regexp twice, just do this instead:

```
split($0, arr, /\(..-av-es\/.*\)/) > 1 {
    ...
}
```

If for some reason you did want to do what you're trying to do then you should do this with GNU awk for strongly typed regexp constants:

```
BEGIN {
    regexp = @/\(..-av-es\/.*\)/
}

$0 ~ regexp {
    split($0, arr, regexp)
    ...
}
```

or with any other awk you're defining a dynamic regexp which is a string that will then get parsed twice by awk, first to turn it into a regexp and then to use it as a regexp, so you need to double the escapes:

```
BEGIN {
    regexp = "\\(..-av-es\\/.*\\)"
}

$0 ~ regexp {
    split($0, arr, regexp)
    ...
}
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for more info on the difference between dynamic regexps, constant regexps, and strongly typed regexp constants.