# Get first n matches with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am using `dbus-monitor` command to see every `Dbus` signal, the command is an infinite loop, so I am using `awk` with it to grep for a specific pattern.

I can get the first match and exit using:

```bash
dbus-monitor --system | awk '/<pattern>/ {print $2; exit}'
```

But, my system is going to a list of states for example `x1 -> x2 -> x3`

I want to use `awk` to get the first 3 signals of a given pattern and print them.

For example, when I start the system, `x1` is sent and I can detect it with the first `awk` command, but when I run it again, I get `x3`, because `x2` is already sent I did not catch it in time.

How can I change `awk` to use for example a counter and get me the first n matches?

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Also, replace the word "pattern" throughout your question with whatever you really mean - partial regexp match, full line regexp, full word regexp, partial string, full word string, full line string, etc. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment a counter variable, then test it to decide whether to exit.

```
dbus-monitor --system | awk '/<pattern>/ {counter++; print $2; if (counter == 3) exit}'
```

Comment: I tried it with `4` but it did not exit, it prints 4 elements and still keeps waiting.

Comment: I just tested this with a log file on our server and it worked.

Comment: To save repeating the variable name: `{print $2; if (++counter == 3) exit}`

Answer (score 0):

you can decrement it down to zero just as easily

> ```
> jot 1000 |
>
> {m,g}awk '__<NF { exit } __>(__-=_^($_ % 181))' FS='^$' __=3
> ```

```
181
362
543
```

The left side portion handles the exit when counter reaches zero, the right side portion handles the pattern you want it to match, plus keep tracking how many times you've printed so far.

here my criteria is simple - find multiples of the prime number 181