# In Bash, I want to get the Nth word of a string after a matching pattern with awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, design-patterns, grep, match

In Bash, I want to get the Nth word of a string after a matching pattern with awk.

Example text:

```
hadf asdfi daf PATTERN asdf dsjk PRINT_THIS asdf adas
asdf sdf PATTERN asdf dasdf PRINT_THIS ads asdf PATTERN ads da PRINT_THIS
ads PATTERN ads da PRINT_THIS
```

Excepted output:

```
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
```

So if a pattern is found, the second word after the match should be output.

How can i do this?

Comment: What's a "pattern"? [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern)

Comment: _How can i do this?_ Probably with `awk`, but it depends on what a pattern is: a glob? a regex? a literal string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using for a greedy match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '.*?\bPATTERN(?:\h+\H+){2}\h+\K\S+' file
```

Perl:

```
perl -lnE 'while (/.*?\bPATTERN(?:\h+\H+){2}\h+(\S+)/g) { say $1; }' file
```

[Demo and explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/UUDETC/1)

Or with awk:

```
awk '/PATTERN[[:blank:]]/{for(i=1;i<=NF-3;i++) if ($i ~ /^PATTERN$/) print $(i+3)}' file
```

All print:

```
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
PRINT_THIS
```

Answer (score 0):

So, should it be *in Bash* **or** *with `awk` or `grep`*? In Bash you can do the following:

```bash
while read -ra tokens; do
  for idx in "${!tokens[@]}"; do
    [[ "${tokens[idx]}" = 'PATTERN' ]] && printf '%s\n' "${tokens[idx + 3]}"
  done
done
```

In case the tokens between `PATTERN` and `PRINT_THIS` cannot contain another `PATTERN`, you could make it a bit more *wannabe*-efficient (and uglier), like this:

```bash
while read -ra tokens; do
  for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#tokens[@]}; ++idx)); do
    [[ "${tokens[idx]}" = 'PATTERN' ]] && printf '%s\n' "${tokens[idx += 3]}"
  done
done
```

Notice the `+=` instead of `+`, as in *“making loops hard to read 101”*.

Last but not least, `declare -i idx step` would make it (even) a tiny bit more efficient.