# Delete a pattern in a file and lines before it using some other pattern

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file containing this :-

```
# Comment
# Comment
# Comment
property1

# Comment
# Comment
property2
```

I wanted to use unix command (awk/sed etc.) to search for a pattern with property2 and then delete all the comments before it. Hence, after operation output should be :-

```
# Comment
# Comment
# Comment
property1
```

This is what I tried (using awk command) :-

```
awk -v pat='^property2' -v comment='^#' '$1~pat{p=NR} p && NR>=p-3{del=($1~comment)} del{next} 1' test.txt
```

Basically, the logic I tried to use was :-

1. Search for property2
2. and then loop over previous 3 lines
3. Search if it is a comment (starts with #)
4. Delete those lines (including the searched pattern and the comments above).

Can someone help me achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please read [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) then [edit] your question to replace `pattern` with whatever you mean. Your example looks like you should be matching a string but your code is trying to match a regexp.

Comment: You description does not accurately match your example--please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This, using any awk, might be what you're trying to do but it's not clear from your question:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$NF != "property2"' file
# Comment
# Comment
# Comment
property1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scriptable editor such as `ed` to:

1. Search for the first match of `property2` (anchored to the beginning of the line)
2. Search backwards from there for a line that does *not* start with `#`
3. From the line *after* this one until one that starts with `property2`, delete those lines
4. `w`rite the file out to disk
5. `q`uit the editor

One way to write that would be:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n'             \
        '/^property2'     \
        '?^[^#]'          \
        '+1,/^property2/d' \
        'w'               \
        'q'               \
  | ed input > /dev/null
```

I've dropped the stdout of `ed` to /dev/null because it will report the lines that it matches along the way, which we're not interested in. `ed` will make the changes to the file "in-place". This ed-script will fail if there is not a non-empty, non-commented line before `property2` (the backwards search will fail).

In your sample input, this will delete the blank line between the stanzas as well, which seems to match your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do; maybe this is it:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat test.txt
# Comment1
# Comment2
# Comment3
property1

# Comment4
# Comment5
property2
Mac_3.2.57$awk '{if(NR==FNR){{if($0!~/^#/&&startFound==1){startFound=0;end=NR};if($0~/^#/&&startFound==0){startFound=1;start=NR}}}else {if(FNR<start||FNR>=end){print}}}' test.txt test.txt
# Comment1
# Comment2
# Comment3
property1

property2
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^#/{:a;N;/^property[^2]/Mb;/^property2/M!ba
             :b;/^#|^property2/!P;s/[^\n]*\n//;tb;d}' file
```

If a line is not a comment, let it be.

Otherwise, accumulate the lines in the pattern space.

If a subsequent line begins with a property that is not 2, print the accumulate lines and repeat.

If a subsequent line does not begin with `property2`, continue accumulating lines.

Otherwise, remove comments and print any lines other than the last which is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-sed` with the `-z` [commandline option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options) to use NUL delimited records reading  the whole input, and replace the match with an empty string:

```
sed -zE 's/(^|\n)#[^\n]*(\n#[^\n]*)*\nproperty2//g' test.txt
```

The pattern matches:

- `(^|\n)#` Either match a newline or assert the start of the string
- `[^\n]*` Match optional characters other than a newline
- `(\n#[^\n]*)*` Optionally repeat matching a newline `#` and optional chars other than a newline
- `\nproperty2` Match a newline and `property2`

Output

```
# Comment
# Comment
# Comment
property1
```