# Why does this awk syntax error occur on rhel7 and not rhel8?

Tags: awk, rhel7, rhel8

Running a build script for a 3rd party library and getting this awk error.

In rhel8 gawk 4.2.1 the follow executes without error:

```
version_num=stable/3.0
printf "3.0.4" | awk "/^${version_num/\//\\\/}/{print;}"
```

but in rhel7 gawk 4.0.2 you get:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /^stable\\/3.0/{print;}
awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ syntax error
```

I think maybe the `/` before `{print;}` is wrong, but it's only a guess and i'm not sure why it works on rhel8...the release notes for the intervening gawk versions didn't show anything that looked relevant.

Comment: This is incorrect use of `awk`. Use `-v` to pass variables

Comment: check your `bash` versions on both systems. I bet you find an older version on one or the other. But note that `/^stable\/whatever/` won't match just `3.0.4`. The anchored match of `/^stable/ means the string must contain `stable` as the first chars. Even without the `^` char, it won''t match. But pluse-uno for providing a perfect [mcve]! Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your question what you're really trying to do but use this as a starting point:

```
version_num='stable/3.0'
printf '3.0.4\n' | awk -v ver="$version_num" 'index($0,ver)'
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information on what that does and why what you currently have is wrong in a few areas.

Answer (score 1):

@`user109078` : `"I think maybe the / before {print;}"` —- your guess is close - it's the other `/` :::

just change ...

> ```
> "/^${version_num/\//\\\/}/{print;}"
> ```

… to …

> ```
> "/^${version_num/\//\\/}/{print;}"
> ```

then it works fine on all my `awk` variants.

- ```
  nawk version 20200816

  program = |/^stable\/3.0/{print;}|
  ```

---

- ```
  mawk 1.3.4

  version_num=stable/3.0;
  printf "3.0.4" | mawk -Wd  "/^${version_num/\//\\/}/{print;}"
  MAIN
  000 . omain
  001 . match0  0x14800c788 /^stable/3.0/
  ```

---

- ```
  gawk 5.2.1

    # gawk profile, created Wed Apr 26 06:13:11 2023

    # Rule(s)

     1  /^stable\/3.0/ {
        print
    }
  ```

That said, like others said, pass shell variables the proper way if possible

For simpler items, if you don't **really** need `regex`, a straight up reference string lookup saves you the need to escape necessary characters

```
version_num=stable/3.0; 

printf "stable/3.0.4" | 

gawk -p- -e 'index($0, __)' __="$version_num"

stable/3.0.4

    # gawk profile, created Wed Apr 26 06:23:34 2023

    # Rule(s)

     1  index($0, __) { # 1
     1      print
    }
```