# how to read multiple lines in a file and put them in grep pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, grep

I have a file t.txt

For example, assuming the file contain values like below. Values changes and do not know what it will change to. I want just to grep what inside the file.

```
[session] cat t.txt
John
Alex
Danny
```

I want to run a command like this to grep for all of them:

```
ls -lart | grep -e John -e Alex -e Danny
```

How i can read those values from t.txt file and put them in pattern as above using -e. I want to grep for whatever values in the file and grep for them all. Those values changes all the time and i want to automate this.

for i in `cat t.txt`
do ls -lart | grep $i
done

I know the above will work. I do not want loop. I want to use grep patter using -e.

Help me guys..

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Your approach would also match a file named `Alexis` or `JohnDoe`. Is this intended?

Comment: Update your example to include substrings and regexp metachars so we can see how you want those handled as its usually trivial to match what you want but harder to not match similar text you don't want, see [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern). Also, `ls ... |` is a bad starting point, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those names are one per line:

```
ls -lart | grep -f t.txt
```

instead of looping.

Comment: Welcome @John ... Please feel free to accept the response if it solved your problem.

Comment: @John Should you really want the `-e pattern` thing here's a slow and convoluted alternative :D  `ls -lart | grep $(awk '{printf "-e %s ", $0}' t.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

To get all directory entries which have one of the lines in t.txt as a substring:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls *+($(paste -s -d '|' t.txt))*
```

To get all directory entries which are exactly one of the lines in t.txt

```
shopt -s extglob
ls +($(paste -s -d '|' t.txt))
```

Turning on *extglob*  enables the `+(...)` globbing, and the `paste` command separates the elements inside the globbing list by vertical bar.