# awk: read pattern from file, awk '$2 !~ /{newline delimited file}/ && $1 > 5000'

Tags: bash, list, file, awk

I have a command that that pipes output like:

```
   1365 8.67.53.0.9
   2657 1.2.3.4
   5956 127.9.9.0
  10463 127.0.0.1
  15670 6.5.4.3.2
  17984 -
```

to:

`awk '$2 !~ /-|127.0.0.1|6.5.4.3.2/ && $1 > 5000'`

which should print:

```
   5956 127.9.9.0
```

or all the ones where `$2` doesn't contain `-`, `127.0.0.1`, or `6.5.4.3.2` and where `$1` is greater than `5000`.

I would like to keep all of the values that should be ignored in a newline delimited file like:

```
-
127.0.0.1
6.5.4.3.2
```

rather than within the regex `/-|127.0.0.1|6.5.4.3.2/` because my list of these will be growing.

Ideally, this could be within a single command and not a function or awk program file. Also, if possible I would like the matching to be more exact (less greedy?). I think the current regex will also match something like 127.0.0.11 or 6.5.4.3.22.

Comment: Note that `.` in a regex doesn't only match itself; it matches _anything_. So `/1.2.3.4/` matches `1A2B3C4`.

Comment: Speaking to your question, though -- awk supports a map datatype, so you can easily add keys to your map to track elements in the ignore file as you read it (take the ignore file as the first input and the data file as the second input, and then you can decide which kind of processing to do depending on which file you're on). Look for any of the (many, many) examples already on this site of folks using `awk` to act like `uniq` and you'll see all the moving parts you need already in use.

Comment: Your regexp isn't anchored so `/1.2.3.4/` also matches the middle of `21.2.3.45`. You should be using full-line string matching, not partial-word regexp matching. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more details on the issue.

Comment: You have an extra `/` in your regex pattern; shouldn't the middle one be a `|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep value to be skipped in a file called `skip` like this:

```bash
cat skip

-
127.0.0.1
6.5.4.3.2
```

Then run `awk` using both files as:

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR {omit[$1]; next} $1 > 5000 && !($2 in omit)' skip file

  5956 127.9.9.0
```

Here:

- While processing first file i.e. `skip` we store all the values in an array `omit`.
- Then while processing main file we simply check if `$1 > 5000` and `$2` doesn't exist in array `omit`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. Is it possible to read the initial $1 and $2 from the output of a previous command piped to the awk, as in, cat file | awk {magic stuff here}

Comment: @SpecialMonkey use `-` to designate input from stdin, eg: `cat file | awk 'magic stuff here' skip -` ; note the last 2 args ... `skip -` => first file processed is `skip` while second 'file' processed is actually stdin (`-`)

Answer (score 2):

Given `input` file:

```
127.0.0.1
6.5.4.3.2
```

and `file` file:

```
   1365 8.67.53.0.9
   2657 1.2.3.4
   5956 127.9.9.0
  10463 127.0.0.1
  15670 6.5.4.3.2
  17984 -
```

```bash
# read input file and perform parameter substitution
$ ips=$(< input); ips=${ips//$'\n'/|}; ips=${ips//./[.]};
# create variable for regex
$ regex="^(-|${ips})$"
# pass regex to awk as variable and run logic
$ awk -v regex="$regex" '$2 !~ regex && $1 >5000' file
   5956 127.9.9.0
```