# How to process a file and replace a pattern with the line number

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

So, I'm trying to design a little program and I'm planning to use a config file and have the ID be the line number. Here's a small example .conf file:

```
ID=_PATTERN_ 
STATE=window 
DIR=_code 
GEO=1200x250+0+32 
CMDS=cd home
```

I'm trying to find a way to replace `_PATTERN_` with the line number. This is mainly because the ID isn't important to the person creating the file, just for the processing script that uses the .conf. So I figured, just make the ID autogenerated through some preprocessing. I was thinking of using `sed` or `awk` but I'm not really sure what to look up to get the answer to this.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Is `_PATTERN_` a string or a regexp? Do you want to do matches on partial words or only full words or something else? Can a string that matches `_PATTERN_` exist anywhere that you do NOT want it to match, e.g. before the `=`? Can it occur multiple times on a line? etc. etc.... [edit] your question to state all of your requirements and show a [mcve] with sample input AND the expected output given that input that covers all of them.

Comment: See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for why we need clarification on your requirements including what you mean by `_PATTERN_`.

Comment: If you would have more than one file with `ID` at first line of each, then you would get same ID for both, is it acceptable? How does `ID`'s value alters processing by said script? Is `ID` value required at all?

Comment: Does it mean that in the file you want to replace all occurances of `_PATTERN_` by the line number, where `_PATTERN_`  occurs? That is, in your example you would then have `ID=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the shell prompt:

```
$ awk '{ gsub(/_PATTERN_/, FNR); print }'
_PATTERN_
1
_PATTERN_ _PATTERN_
2 2
foo _PATTERN_
foo 3
```

Comment: Thank you that does just what I want! Could you explain gsub and FWR for me though?

Comment: Better than `man gawk` or a good book or tutorial? Unlikely.

Comment: The script can be simplified a bit like: `awk '{ gsub(/_PATTERN_/, NR)}1'` :). `gsub` replace pattern with string, `NR` (`FNR`) mean number of record (line), `1` mean print "edited" line.

Comment: @RomeoNinov The jargon for that kind of simplification is "golfed". (See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Kaz, I am not so good for codegolf :)

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting, that in this approache, _PATTERN_  is interpreted as a _POSIX 1003.2 regular expression_. This may or may not be what the OP wants; unfortunately, there is no hint in the question saying what the pattern really is. In particular, if the OP sees the pattern as literal string, your solution would not work.

Comment: @user1934428 Unless, you know, any regex characters occurring in the pattern were backslash escaped. It also seems the pattern is under OP's control, and not externally imposed.

Comment: @Kaz: Sure, but this must then be part of the definition of the build file. As I understood the OP, he gets the configuration file from somewhere. If the OP himself can dictate the syntax for the build file, he can of course define any pattern syntax he wants.