# How to take text from one part of a file and insert into another part of the same file?

Tags: awk, sed

So, imagine I have a whole bunch of files like so:

```
a line of text
% !TEX TS-parameter = ../
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
\gresetgregpath{{music/}}
a line of text
a line of text
```

I need to copy the relative path `../` from the line where it appears near the top of the file into the spot between `\gresetgregpath{{` and `music/}}` later in the file:

```
a line of text
% !TEX TS-parameter = ../
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
\\gresetgregpath{{../music/}}
a line of text
a line of text
```

The relative path differs from file to file, but `% !TEX TS-parameter =`  will always precede it and it will always be terminated by an end of line.  `% !TEX TS-parameter =`  does not occur on any other line.  The line that defines the destination (`\gresetgregpath{{music/}`) is identical in all files and is guaranteed to appear only once in each file.  The lines represented by `a line of text` are otherwise arbitrary in both number and contents.

Given that I have a huge number of files to do this on, I'd like to do it in bulk with something like sed or awk.  So how to I copy some text from one line and put it into the same file in a specific location on another line latter in the same file?

I have not tried anything myself at this point because I've only used sed for single line operations and have never used awk.

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempts and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: @EdMorton, I did not believe that information to be pertinent to the answer, hence my elimination of it.  I have now added that information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can tell this **should** work for any characters in your input or search strings (if any of them can contain `'` then use `'\''` to represent that in the string definition) as its only doing literal string operations:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

srcMrkr='% !TEX TS-parameter = '        \
dstMrkr='\gresetgregpath{{music/}}'     \
dstOfmt='\gresetgregpath{{%smusic/}}'   \
awk '
    index($0,ENVIRON["srcMrkr"]) == 1 {
       info = substr($0,length(ENVIRON["srcMrkr"])+1)
    }
    $0 == ENVIRON["dstMrkr"] {
        $0 = sprintf(ENVIRON["dstOfmt"],info)
    }
    { print }
' file
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
a line of text
% !TEX TS-parameter = ../
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
\gresetgregpath{{../music/}}
a line of text
a line of text
```

See [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) and [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for issues related to metacharacters and substrings during "pattern" matching and replacement.

Comment: All the provided answers work for me, but I'm accepting this one because putting the awk program in a separate file helped me combine several steps that I had been planning to do separately into a single step.  That's a bonus I wasn't expecting.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated with your example update...)

With awk:

```
awk -v marker="% !TEX TS-parameter = " '
$0~"^" marker {s=$0; sub(marker,"", s)} 
$0~/^\\gresetgregpath/ {
        sub(/{{music\/}}/,"{{" s "music/}}")
}
1' file
```

But personally I am using Ruby for a replacement for awk/sed/Perl/Bash these days:

```
ruby -e 'BEGIN{
    src=/^% !TEX TS-parameter = (.*)/
    tgt_m=/^(\\gresetgregpath){{([^}]*)}}/
}
txt=$<.read
info=txt.match(src)[1]
puts txt.sub(tgt_m, "\\1{{#{info}\\2}}")
' file
```

The advantage of the Ruby is that you can glob from within Ruby with more control and you can read an external mapping easily.

Either of those prints:

```
a line of text
% !TEX TS-parameter = ../
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
\gresetgregpath{{../music/}}
a line of text
a line of text
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
a line of text
some marker: useful_information
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
I need to insert here
a line of text
a line of text
```

then

```
awk '/^some marker:/{info=substr($0,14)}{sub(/insert here/,"insert " info " here");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
a line of text
some marker: useful_information
a line of text
a line of text
a line of text
I need to insert useful_information here
a line of text
a line of text
```

Explanation: for line starting with `some marker:` grab [substr](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)ing start at 14th character (as some marker: with following space has 13 characters) and put it into variable named `info`. Then replace `insert here` using concatenation of insert space information space here, if there is not insert here in line it is no operation. After doing that `print` line. Disclaimer: this code assume info is empty string if there is not some marker before insert here.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*