# Find the highest number value in file names

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I've been doing research for 3 days now, so I'm putting my question here. I have a script that I use to standardize my TV series. In the end, everything looks like this syntax:
`([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)(\d{1,3})`
Here's an example:
**Here it all begins_S01E51.mkv**

I'd like to find and rename the last episode of the season.
Example:
**Here it all begins_S01E51 - Final.mkv**

Could someone help me find a solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do all the shows have this format? Specifically, is it "<Episode Name>`Underscore`S<Season Number>E<Episode Number>`dot`<File Suffix>"?

Comment: What have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard)? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer that question plus provide a minimal reproducible example with concise, testable sample input (not just 1 string with 1 show name `Here it all begins_`), expected output, and your code attempt to solve your problem yourself so we can help you. By the way, what you have written after "everything looks like this syntax:", i.e. `([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)(\d{1,3})`, is regexp notation that's undefined by POSIX (it looks like a PCRE) and so will do different things if used in different versions of the mandatory POSIX tools.

Comment: @Morton In fact, I've tried out a bunch of codes found here and elsewhere.
things like:
`ls ([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)*|sort -rn|head -1`
or else:
`find -regextype egrep -iregex ".([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)[0-9]+.*" | egrep -i -o "file[0-9]*" | sed 's/file//' | sort -r-n | head -n1`
and many more. 

The fact is, I'm still learning and haven't mastered all these concepts yet... The cmd `sort` and its options, `egrep`, `head or tail -n(a number)` and so on.

Expressions such as:
`-regextype egrep -iregex` sound like Chinese to me.

Comment: @Morton I know what POSIX is. But for example, I don't know what PCRE is. In my head, an expression like: `([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)(\d{1,3})` is an expression that Bash understands. I often use these tools to rename files. I test them on regexr.com and very often get a good result.


Now I'm at the point where I want to go further. More advanced notions taken separately are well defined in my research. But when it comes to combining them all... With every question I've asked here, I've always learned something very useful, which has helped me to improve. Forgive the fact that I'm a novice.

Comment: @Uberhumus 
Yes, my current script successfully renames all files in this exact format. Now I'm at the point where I want to go further in my learning process and add even more commands for greater precision and more options. I take a lot of very long courses on programming, but theory and practice are two separate things. I've learned a lot more about applying theory by asking questions here. There are always new concepts in people's answers that enlighten me beyond my expectations ;-)

Comment: The first hit from googling PCRE (https://www.google.com/search?q=PCRE), i.e. https://www.pcre.org/, tells you what it is - a Perl Compatible Regular Expression. `\w`, `\d`, and `\s` are not part of Basic Regular Expressions (BREs as used by sed and grep by default) or Extended Regular Expressions (EREs as in `grep -E` and GNU BSD `sed -E`) as POSIX tools and bash support in their regular expressions. Some GNU tools have extensions to support `\w` and `\s` in their ERE regexps, but bash doesn't and none of them support `\d`. GNU grep has a `-P` flag to use PCREs instead of BREs or EREs.

Comment: By the way, to ping me in a comment use `@EdMorton`, not just `@Morton` as the latter wouldn't be pinging me, it'd be pinging someone else with that user name. I only saw these by coincidence as I happened to scroll up after reading your comment under my answer.

Comment: By the way, `egrep` has been obsolete for almost 20 years in favor of `grep -E`.

Comment: So no, bash would not understand `([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)(\d{1,3})` as you want it to be understood but in the code in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402725/find-the-highest-number-value-in-file-names/77404658#comment136469054_77402725), you're first asking `find` to understand it, which it won't either, then asking bash to understand it in the call to `ls` as given `ls ([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)*` it's the shell that would interpret `([\w\d\s]+)(_S(\d{2})E)*` as a globbing pattern and expand that to a list of file names and THAT is what `ls` would see as it's arguments

Comment: When doing pattern matching (either finding file names or finding text within files) unfortunately you must learn the difference between strings, BREs, EREs, PCREs, and globbing patterns as well as what it means to do full-line, full-field, full-word, partial-line, partial-field, partial-word matching or your resulting code will be fragile and/or inefficient and/or non-portable if it works at all. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info on some of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255836/discussion-between-martin-julien-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the files, use parameter expansion to extract the episode number. Store the maximum in a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
max=0
for f in 'Here it all begins_S01E'*.mkv ; do
    n=${f##*E}   # Remove everything up to the last E.
    n=${n%.mkv}  # Remove the extension.
    if (( n > max )) ; then
        max=$n
    fi
done
echo 'Here it all begins_S01E'$max.mkv
```

To make it work over series and seasons, too, extract the series and season in a similar way. Now we need to store a maximum per series and season, we can take advantage of an associative array for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A season
for f in *.mkv ; do
    series=${f%%_S[0-9]*}
    s=${f##*S}
    s=${s%%E*}
    e=${f##*E}
    e=${e%.mkv}
    if (( e > season[${series}_S$s] )) ; then
        season[${series}_S$s]=$e
    fi
done
for s in "${!season[@]}" ; do
    echo "${s}E${season[$s]}.mkv"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the common [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) we can list your files in decreasing episode order with:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *.mkv |
    sed 's/.*E\([0-9]*\).*/\1\t&/' | sort -rn | cut -f2-
Some other show_S02E51.mkv
Some other show_S01E51.mkv
Here it all begins_S01E51.mkv
Some other show_S02E50.mkv
Some other show_S01E50.mkv
Here it all begins_S01E50.mkv
```

and we can get just the first episode of each season of each series with a pipe to awk:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *.mkv |
    sed 's/.*E\([0-9]*\).*/\1\t&/' | sort -rn | cut -f2- |
    awk '{ssn=$0; sub(/E[^E]+$/,"",ssn)} !seen[ssn]++'
Some other show_S02E51.mkv
Some other show_S01E51.mkv
Here it all begins_S01E51.mkv
```

and from there you can do whatever you like to move those files, e.g.:

```
$ while IFS= read -r old; do
     new="${old%.mkv} - Final.mkv"
     echo mv -- "$old" "$new"
done < <(
        printf '%s\n' *.mkv |
            sed 's/.*E\([0-9]*\).*/\1\t&/' | sort -rn | cut -f2- |
            awk '{ssn=$0; sub(/E[^E]+$/,"",ssn)} !seen[ssn]++'
    )
mv -- Some other show_S02E51.mkv Some other show_S02E51 - Final.mkv
mv -- Some other show_S01E51.mkv Some other show_S01E51 - Final.mkv
mv -- Here it all begins_S01E51.mkv Here it all begins_S01E51 - Final.mkv
```

Remove the `echo` when done testing that the correct file names are selected to make it really `mv` the files.

The above will work with any POSIX version of the tools used.

Comment: Just WOW... It's going to take me a good two weeks to analyze and research everything in order to understand what happened, but it goes even further than I originally imagined. Not only does it work, but I can put every episode from every season into a single folder! I didn't see that one coming! EdMorton, you're a genius!

Comment: Now... How can I make this work regardless of the extension? i.e. `(mp4|avi|mkv|flv|wmv|mpg|mov|ts|whatever)`

It has to be a bit more complex, doesn't it?

Comment: It'd be a trivial tweak but I assume you're using the answer you accepted so you should ask them about how to enhance that, it'll be a similar change with either solution. Actually, you should ask a new question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.