# How to find string and replace some string between { ... }?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

You only need to change the port in the /test/v2.0.0 block:

```
server {
    location /test/v2.0.3 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
}
```

`sed '0,/:[0-9].*;/{s/:[0-9].*;/:5555;/}' test.nginx`
- changes the first match

`sed '/.*location.*\/test\/v2.0.0\/.*:[0-9].*;/{s/:[0-9].*;/:5555;/}' test.nginx`
- doesn't change anything

`sed 's/.*location.*\/test\/v2.0.0\/.*:[0-9].*;/:5555;/' test.nginx`
- doesn't change anything

P.S.:

What the task sounds like:
Find location `/test/v2.0.0.0` preceded by any character except `#`, select everything in the brackets `{` `}`, find the port string `:3000`; between them, replace it with the specified one.

Output:

```
server {
    location /test/v2.0.3 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:5555;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the general case, nginx configuration files can be much more complicated to parse correctly. eg. what if there is an `include` directive? or nested `{ ... }` context?

Comment: this is for file *.locations, for much more complicated i don't think right now

Comment: sed is an excellent too for doing `s/regexp/string/` on individual lines, for anything else (cases that involve multiple lines, cases that need to [search for literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), cases where replacement text may contain backreferences, etc.) just use awk for some combination of clarity, portability, robustness, efficiency, maintainability, etc.

Comment: To allow us to really test a potential solution you should add blocks that look like the target block but start with  `location foo/test/v2.0.0.0` and `location /test/v2.0.0.0` and `location /test/v210.0` at the top of your sample input/output to test for a couple of cases of potential regexp and substring false matches.

Comment: In all pattern matching it's much easier to write code that matches the text you want (e.g. `.*` matches anything but is rarely the right solution) than to NOT match similar text you don't want so it's important to cover the rainy day cases in your sample input/output or you're likely to get solutions that ONLY work for the sunny day cases you provide in your question and then fail later on the real world data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should this not be done using sed?

> In the simplest calling of sed, it has *one* line of text in the pattern space, ie. 1 line of \n delimited text from the input

see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/407145

Doing it using awk is not very hard:

```
awk '/test\/v2.0.0/{ found=1; }found==1 && /:[0-9]{4}/{ gsub(/:[0-9]{4}/,":5555"); found=0 }1' test.nginx
```

- When a line with `test/v2.0.0` is found (the `/` needs to be escaped), the variable found is set to 1
- When found is equal to 1 and a `:` is found followed by four numbers, it is replaced by `:5555`
- After the change `found` should be reset. NOTE: Only the first occurrence after `test/v2.0.0` is changed now...
- The `1` at the end makes the (changed) line being outputted.

Comment: thx u vary much, this works too, but too have bug, if change 2.0.0 on 2.0.3 ports in all locations changed on 5555

Comment: @Hardwarenoob: I made a change

Comment: My mistake, sry, all works, just i'm forgot what write changes in file in last test

Comment: All those `.`s in `/test\/v2.0.0/` need to be escaped or it'll match `/test/v23010` or anything similar. You also need start/end anchors to avoid substring matches. Personally I'd use `$2 == "/test/v2.0.0/"` or similar instead per the mantra that if you want something treated as a string, it's simpler and more robust to use a string operator than trying to escape regexp metachars (we all frequently miss some, as in this case) so you can use a regexp operator but make it behave as it it was a string one.

Comment: I was thinking in regular expressions, because of the question...  I should have taken one step back, and noticed that a string comparison is better than a regular expression (in this case)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below `awk` to achieve your result.

```bash
awk '
/location \/test\/v2\.0\.0/ {flag=1}
flag && /proxy_pass/ {sub(/:[0-9]+;/, ":5555;")}
/}/ {flag=0}
{print}
' your_file
```

**The above command will:**

1. Set a `flag` when the line containing location `/test/v2.0.0` is found(notice `.` is escaped).
2. If the flag is set and the line contains `proxy_pass`, it will substitute the port number with `5555`.
3. When the closing brace(`}`) is found, the `flag` is unset and each line will be printed.

**Using [pattern range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html#Specifying-Record-Ranges-with-Patterns) `awk`(h/t: 
*[dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)*):**

```bash
awk '/location \/test\/v2\.0\.0/,/}/ {if(/proxy_pass/) sub(/:[0-9]+;/,":5555;")}1' your_file
```

*[demo here](https://ideone.com/B21Dvm)*

---

##### With `sed`:

Let me first highlight the problems in your tried commands:

1. `sed '0,/:[0-9].*;/{s/:[0-9].*;/:5555;/}'` -  This command will replace the first port number it finds in the file, **regardless** of whether it is inside the /test/v2.0.0 block or not.
2. The second and third commands try to find a line that contains both location `/test/v2.0.0` and the *port number*, but in your configuration file, these two elements are on separate lines.

You can try something like:

```
sed '/location \/test\/v2\.0\.0/,/}/ s/\(proxy_pass http:\/\/10.1.0.6:\)[0-9]*;/\15555;/'
```

*[demo here](https://ideone.com/BnMdGT)*

---

<sub>Footnote: The above commands assume the simple configuration file as you mentioned without nested contexts. If the config file is a complex one, please consider using some ***[parsers](https://github.com/iafan/Config-Neat)*** which would make your job easy.</sub>

Comment: thx u very much, its works, i need to learn awk, because on sed very hard find answers, 3 hours in google and only copy/paste useless answers.

Comment: awk has two-pattern range which does the flag for you: `awk '/location \/test\/v2.0.0/,/}/ {if(/proxy_pass/) sub(/:[0-9]+;/,":5555;")} {print}' infile`. You can also save a little typing by using `1` instead of `{print}` but not everyone likes this. @Hardwarenoob: sed can actually do the same as long as you don't have any :number that isn't a desired port in the selected range: `sed '/location \/test\/v2.0.0/,/}/ s/:[0-9]+;/:5555;/' infile`

Comment: note that real nginx configuration files can have nested contexts, so seeing a `}` does not guarantee one has reached the end of a `location {`

Comment: See [my comment under another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77891011/how-to-find-string-and-replace-some-string-between#comment137325833_77891151).

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples and efforts please try following GNU `awk` solution. Using regex `[[:space:]]+proxy_pass[[:space:]]+http:\\/\\/[^;]+;` in this solution.

```
awk -v change="2" -v RS='[[:space:]]+proxy_pass[[:space:]]+http:\\/\\/[^;]+;' '
RT{
  if(++count==change){
    match(RT,/([^/]*\/\/)([^:]*:)(.*$)/,arr)
    RT=arr[1] arr[2] "5555"
  }
  print $0 RT
}
END{
  if($0){ print }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk and only using [full-field string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) on specific fields to avoid any false matches with simular strings due to regexp metachars or substrings:

```
$ awk '
    $1 == "location" { inTgt = ($2 == "/test/v2.0.0") }
    inTgt && ($1 == "proxy_pass") { sub(/:[^:]+;/,":5555;") }
    { print }
' file
server {
    location /test/v2.0.3 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:5555;
    }
}
```

The above was run on the sample input the OP provided, but here's some that's more useful for testing a couple of potential rainy day cases:

```
$ cat file
server {
    location foo/test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v210.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.3 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
$ awk '
    $1 == "location" { inTgt = ($2 == "/test/v2.0.0") }
    inTgt && ($1 == "proxy_pass") { sub(/:[^:]+;/,":5555;") }
    { print }
' file
server {
    location foo/test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v210.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.3 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:3000;
    }
    location /test/v2.0.0 {
        modsecurity on;
        proxy_pass http://10.1.0.6:5555;
    }
}
```