# Delete first three lines containing a certain word

Tags: shell, sed

I am having a bit of trouble with a `sed` command. I need to delete the first 3 lines that contain a specified word from a file.

My `sed` command only checks the first 6 lines, whether or not they contain the word. It deletes the lines containing the word, but it stops after 6 lines, not after 3 lines that contain the word.

This is my command:

```
sed "1,6{/.*$word.*/d;}" "$filename"`
```

So, for example, I want to delete the first 3 lines containing the word "please", for the file content:

```
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
1 please delete this line
leave this line alone
2 please delete this line
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
3 please delete this line
leave this line alone
```

The output is:

```
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
leave this line alone
3 please delete this line
leave this line alone
```

Comment: The fact that a `sed` question has not been answered inside an hour indicates something is wrong - your question is poorly formatted. Please click [edit] and select your code with your mouse, then click `{}` in the formatting toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code

Comment: This question has ***not*** been answered as @kana explicitly and unmistakably requires the deletions to be limited to the first 15 occurrences.

Comment: @tripleee, this is not a duplicate; please read the details and re-open.

Comment: I can't add an answer because this question was closed erroneously, but the problem is that the command specifies `1,6`, which will match only the first 6 lines. You could write a `sed` script that does what you want, but not a one-liner. On the other hand, this is easy to do with `awk`, like this: `awk '/.*please.*/ {n++} !/.*please.*/ || n > 3 {print}'`. There are actually two "lines" here. The first one just matches lines that contain the word `please` and counts them. The second prints lines that do _not_ (`!`) contain the word, or all lines after it finds 3 matches.

Comment: @AdamLiss Thanks for the feedback; reopened (though quite reluctantly, as the error is quite obvious and `sed` is hardly the right tool for this).

Comment: Should a line like `I am displeased with this` be printed or not? Can `word` contain non-alphabetic characters? How about regexp metachars? This is a [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) type of question.

Comment: I am glad that the reopening gave way to a burst of answers.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the quick response! I'm fine with the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), as the OP is new to SO, and I hope this will help them learn to ask questions effectively.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, an `awk` solution is simple.

For example:

```
awk '!index($0,q) || ++c>n' n=3 q=please "$filename"
```

or slightly more confusingly but more efficiently (since we can stop checking lines after we've found three matches):

```
awk 'c==n || !index($0,q) || !++c' n=3 q=please "$filename"
```

---

It is not very convenient to try to count with `sed`, although it is possible. Parameterising arguments is also complicated.

Ignoring both those issues, here is a sed script to delete the first 3 occurrences of lines containing "please":

```
sed '
    /please/ {
        x
        s/././3
        x
        t
        x
        s/^/ /
        x
        d
    }
' "$filename"
```

Like the second awk, we can avoid scanning lines after we have found enough matches:

```
sed '
    /please/!b
    x
    s/././3
    x
    t flush
    x
    s/^/^/
    x
    d
:flush
    n
    b flush
' "$filename"
```

Applying any script to:

```
1 leave this line alone
2 leave this line alone
1 please delete this line
3 leave this line alone
2 please delete this line
4 leave this line alone
5 leave this line alone
3 please delete this line
6 leave this line alone
4 please leave this line alone
7 leave this line alone
```

produces:

```
1 leave this line alone
2 leave this line alone
3 leave this line alone
4 leave this line alone
5 leave this line alone
6 leave this line alone
4 please leave this line alone
7 leave this line alone
```

Comment: Upvote for the elegant use of `awk`, particularly for accepting the keyword and the count as variables.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed offers a simpler way to do it,

```
sed '0,/word/{//d}
     0,/word/{//d}
     0,/word/{//d}
'
```

or even, since there's only the one search,

```
sed '/word/ { 0,//{//d}; 0,//{//d}; 0,//{//d}; }'
```

which also scans each line only once, to fix a (minor but possibly measurable) scaling issue noticed in comments.

Comment: This might be programmed using gnu parallel `parallel -n 0  echo '0,/please/{//d}' ::: { 1..3} | sed -f - file`

Comment: @potong or `yes '0,/please/{//d}'| head 3 | sed -f - file`. probably slow on large files with large N since we scan every line N times, instead of just once

Comment: @jhnc good point, if you also didn't like it on too-hacky grounds you're going to *hate* the fix for the performance :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/please/{x;s/^./&/m3;x;t;H;d}' file
```

Use the hold space as a counter for the lines containing the word `please`.

If a line contains `please` then:

Swap to the hold space, substitute the first character of the third line with itself and swap back to the pattern space.

If the substitution was successful, carry out no further processing of this line.

Otherwise, append the line to the hold space and delete the current line.

Comment: not sure why the downvote. I thought about doing it this way (but just `s/\n/\n/3` instead of the gnu-ism) but figured scanning the lines repetitvely was less efficient, even if the code is a few characters shorter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command specifies `1,6`, which will match only the first 6 lines. You could write a `sed` script that does what you want, but not a one-liner.

On the other hand, this is easy to do with `awk`, like this:

```
awk '/.*please.*/ {n++} !/.*please.*/ || n > 3 {print}'
```

There are actually two "lines" here. The first one just matches lines that contain the word "please" and counts them. The second prints lines that do not (`!`) contain the word, or all lines after it finds 3 matches.