# using awk with conditions on different lines

Tags: unix, awk

If 2 lines after the line with "AA", $3 of the line is > 80(here 89 so yes) , I want to cat the line with "AA" and "CC".

```
aaaaaaaa AA [15]
bbbbbbbb BB [60]
cccccccc CC [89]
dddddddd DD [52]
```

I tried this :

```
gawk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "AA" && $I+2 > 80) print $I,$I+2}' ~/Desktop/toto.txt
```

output desired :

```
aaaaaaaa AA [15]
cccccccc CC [89]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'[[ ]+' '$2=="AA"{prev=$0; nr=NR+2} (NR==nr) && ($3 >80){print prev ORS $0}' file
aaaaaaaa AA [15]
cccccccc CC [89]
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'[[ ]+' '$2=="AA"{prev=$0; c=3} (c&&!--c) && ($3>80){print prev ORS $0}' file
aaaaaaaa AA [15]
cccccccc CC [89]
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for an explanation of `c&&!--c` and related examples.

Comment: When I try $3>100 it does not work, do you know why please ?

Comment: do you know please also how to do If I want to add the condition that the $2 of the 2nd line start by B ? thank you

Comment: 1) No - must be something different about your data from what you posted, there's nothing magic about the number 100 vs 80. 2) `$2 ~/^B/`. 3) You're welcome!

Comment: maybe because sometimes numbers are like that [56 ] or [1 ] instead of [56] or [1]

Comment: None of those differences in the input would affect the calculation. You'd have to post some actual data that the script doesn't work for for me to be able to help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```sh
awk '{val = $3; gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", val)} prno && NR == prno+2 && val > 80 {print p ORS $0} $2 == "AA" {prno = NR; p = $0}' file

aaaaaaaa AA [15]
cccccccc CC [89]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```sh
awk -F '[][ ]+' '
    $2 == "AA" {
        aa = $0
        getline; getline
        if ($3 > 80) {
            print aa
            print
        }
    }
' file
```

Comment: To readers: read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline after this answer