# Remove the second occurrence if match occurs

Tags: awk, sed

I have data as

```
Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
function (A+B)
function (A1A2)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
function ((B1+B2)A2)
```

I want output as

```
Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
```

I want to get only the 1st function line printed if function is repeated.

I tried

```
awk "/function/ && !a[$0]++{print;next} !/function/{delete a;print}" file
```

But I am getting no change in data.

Comment: `awk '/Cell/{print; getline; print}' file`?

Comment: If you're using double quotes because you're running on Windows then you should add that tag to the question. If that's not the reason then - don't do that. In Unix always quote strings (including scripts) with single quotes until if/when you **need** double quotes to get the shell involved to interpret the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Cyrus' in the comments, my first thought was printing record at `Cell` and then next line, but if you need it the other way around:

```
$ awk '/function/&&f{print p ORS $0;f=0}{p=$0}/Cell/{f=1}' file
```

Output:

```
Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/function/ && f {   # seeing "function" when the f flag is up
    print p ORS $0  # print stored previous and current records
    f=0             # flag down
}
{
    p=$0            # store current as previous for next round
}
/Cell/ {            # at "Cell"
    f=1             # flag up
}' file
```

(You could store the `Cell` as the `f` flag's value and `print` when that is set:

```
$ awk '/function/&&f{print f ORS $0;f=""}/Cell/{f=$0}'
```

)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/^Cell.*\nfunction/p;D' file
```

Turn on explicit printing by setting the option `-n`.

Append the next line.

If the first line begins `Cell` and the second line begins `function` print them.

Delete the first line and repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/Cell/{c=2} c&&c--' file
Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
```

or if "Cell" isn't always the text in the non-function block:

```
$ awk '!/function/{c=2} c&&c--' file
Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for details.

Answer (score 1):

this trick will do

```
$ uniq -w8 file

Cell A
function (A+B)
Cell B
function (A^B)
Cell C
function (A1A2)
```

compares "function".length() -> 8 characters.
`uniq` will eliminate contiguous repeated entries, so always the first one will be selected.

If your Cell lines are not repeated contiguously this will be the shortest code.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU uniq for `-w`.