# Delete the line above a pattern

Tags: shell, awk, sed, text-processing

I'm trying to delete lines that contain a certain pattern and the line directly above this specific pattern in a file. The pattern is 'Query '. The file looks something like this:

```
1. Query= ENST00000641267.1
2. Query= ENST00000641448.1
3. Query= MSTRG.3294.1
4. Query= ENST00000435134.2
5. Query= ENST00000503142.1
6. Query= ENST00000503142.1
7. Query    8  THSLRYFRLGVSDPIHGVPEFISVGYVDSHPITTYDSVTQQKEPRAPWMAENLVPDHWER 187
8. Query  188  YTQLLKGWQQMFRVELKRQQRHYNHSGSHTYQRMIGCELLEDGSTTGFLQYAYDGQNFLI 367
9. Query  368  FNKDTLS*LAVDNVAHTIKRAREANQHELQYQKNWLEEECIA*LKRFLEYGKDTQQ 535
10. Query= ENST00000612670.1
11. Query    1  MVFTQAPAEIMGHLRICSLLARQCLAEFLGVFVLMLLTQGAVAQAVTSGETKGNFFTMFL 180
12. Query  181  AGSLAVTIAIYVGGNVSG 234
13. Query= MSTRG.3309.1
```

So line 6 to 12 should be deleted while all other lines should be preserved. I've tried the following to remove the line before the pattern but can't get it to work:

```
tac | sed '/Query /'I, +1 d' | tac file.txt > newfile.txt
```

It just outputs the '>' sign.
Can anyone help with this?

Desired output is:

```
    1. Query= ENST00000641267.1
    2. Query= ENST00000641448.1
    3. Query= MSTRG.3294.1
    4. Query= ENST00000435134.2
    5. Query= ENST00000503142.1
    13. Query= MSTRG.3309.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use the approach in this answer to a similar question to yours: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29928/438036

Comment: Is it line from 6 to 12 to delete or line 6 and 12 ? it is not clear.

Comment: Why would you like to delete line 6-12 only? All the lines has the word `Query` though.

Comment: @cyrus and Itération 122442 I changed the question

Comment: This might help with your example: `tac file | sed '/Query /,/Query=/d' | tac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\n.*Query /D;/Query /!P;D' file
```

Append the next line (unless the current line is the last line).

If the appended line contains `Query` , delete the first line and go again.

If the first line of the 2 line window contains `Query` , don't print it.

Otherwise print the first of the 2 lines, delete it and go again.

N.B. The appending of the next line is dependant on it not being the last, as the default behaviour of sed is print the pattern space if the `N` command is called to read passed the end of the file. This allows the last line to treated properly i.e. if the last line contains `Query`  it will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tac file | awk '/Query /{c=2} !(c&&c--)' | tac
1. Query= ENST00000641267.1
2. Query= ENST00000641448.1
3. Query= MSTRG.3294.1
4. Query= ENST00000435134.2
5. Query= ENST00000503142.1
13. Query= MSTRG.3309.1
```

See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1. Query= ENST00000641267.1
2. Query= ENST00000641448.1
3. Query= MSTRG.3294.1
4. Query= ENST00000435134.2
5. Query= ENST00000503142.1
6. Query= ENST00000503142.1
7. Query    8  THSLRYFRLGVSDPIHGVPEFISVGYVDSHPITTYDSVTQQKEPRAPWMAENLVPDHWER 187
8. Query  188  YTQLLKGWQQMFRVELKRQQRHYNHSGSHTYQRMIGCELLEDGSTTGFLQYAYDGQNFLI 367
9. Query  368  FNKDTLS*LAVDNVAHTIKRAREANQHELQYQKNWLEEECIA*LKRFLEYGKDTQQ 535
10. Query= ENST00000612670.1
11. Query    1  MVFTQAPAEIMGHLRICSLLARQCLAEFLGVFVLMLLTQGAVAQAVTSGETKGNFFTMFL 180
12. Query  181  AGSLAVTIAIYVGGNVSG 234
13. Query= MSTRG.3309.1
```

then

```
awk 'NR>1&&!/Query /&&prev!~/Query /{print prev}{prev=$0}END{if(prev!~/Query /){print prev}}' file.txt
```

output

```
1. Query= ENST00000641267.1
2. Query= ENST00000641448.1
3. Query= MSTRG.3294.1
4. Query= ENST00000435134.2
5. Query= ENST00000503142.1
13. Query= MSTRG.3309.1
```

Explanation: I use `prev` variable to store previous line, if current line does not match `Query`  and previous line does not match `Query`  then I print previous line. As I `print` previous line I need to consider last line separately, for which I use `END`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*