# Is it possible to show all lines after match with grep/ripgrep?

Tags: grep

I have a large file, and I want to show all lines after a match. Right now I am doing this:

```bash
cat file | grep -A99999 "FOO"
```

Basically this command would break if that file is longer than 99999 lines, is it possible to grep all lines after a match?

Comment: I believe you can find the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file

Comment: Not with `grep` but with `sed` or `awk` yes

Comment: `awk '/FOO/{f=1} f' file` which is idiom "a" at [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105).