# Conditionally get the 2nd or 4th line after a match with AWK?

Tags: bash, awk

Working from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1075247), I'm using c)

> Print the Nth record after some regexp
> `awk 'c&&!--c;/regexp/{c=N}' file`

to summarise test results (i.e. the test fail detail is two lines after the test suite name that starts with '●'), but I noticed there's some occasions I need to instead print out the 4th line below, if the second line matches a string.

Here are the two cases

```
 ● Test Suite > Use case >  
 
 Type Error: Illegal constructor
```

and

```
● Test Suite > Use case >

Expected test not to call console.error // <--- when I see this...

If the error is expected ...

Warning: Failed prop type ... // <-- ...I want this line
```

Is there a way to conditionally get the 4th line after if the second line after ● matches a pattern or the second line itself otherwise?

Comment: Have you checked you can match `'●'`? Shell utilities handle single-byte ASCII text. Some have UTF-8 support. What is `'●'` you are attempting to match? I see it as the multi-byte character `0xe2`, `0x97`, `0x8f`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah it does.

Comment: `awk '/regex1/ {c=2}; c==1 && /regex2/ {c+=2}; c && !--c' file`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet today might do it. I'll have to check with I can get back to work

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to structure it more like a state machine and do different things in different states. First you'll be looking for a test case, and then once you've found it, you'll be scanning for the line you need to print:

```
BEGIN {
  state="LOOKING";
}

state == "LOOKING" && /^●/ {
  state = "FOUND";
  c = 0;
  next;
}

state == "FOUND" && /^Expected test not to call console\.error/ {
  c = 1;
  next;
}

state == "FOUND" && c == 0 {
  print;
  state = "LOOKING";
  next;
}

state == "FOUND" {
  c--;
}
```

Note that I based the values to set `c` to on your description of the input data. But it looks like the data you give in the question has extra blank lines, in which case the lines I think you want to print out are the 3rd and 7th. In that case, change the `awk` program to set `c` to `1` when switching the state to `FOUND` and to `3` when skipping a few more lines after matching `/^Expected.../`.