# Find duplicate text in a line, delete that whole line and its successor line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Due to my last question was closed and after some own testings I want to try to post another question to get the correct answer hopefully.

I want to remove some duplicated lines in a text file.
Every line has some fixed strings that should act as some kind of starting point to check for duplicated text until the end of that line.
When duplicate was found this whole line including its successor line right underneath should get deleted. Every first occurrency should be kept.
Texfile looks like

```
somerandomtexthere fixedstring somepossibledupetext <- 1st line
line to also delete if dupe right above             <- 2nd line
somerandomtexthere fixedstring somepossibledupetext <- 3rd line
line to also delete if dupe right above             <- 4th line
...
```

So my idea finally is to use that fixed string as starting point to ensure only dupes in lines 13579 etc are recognized and it wont scan lines 246810 because "starting string" only occurs in 13579.
Hopefully this will prevent messing around the whole textfile because 246810 could also have dupes.

As example if line 1 and 9 has dupe text found between string and end of line, the lines 9 and 10 should get removed from file and line 1 and 2 should stay.
I hope this is as clear as it could be. :)

Is this task possible with sed or awk?

What I tried was something like

```
`awk '!(seen[$0]++&&(skip=1)||skip&&!(skip=0))'
or
awk '!seen[$0]++||getline&&0'
```

Both wil find and eleminate duplicated lines and their respective successor line but unfortunatly when diving deeper into the results it messed up my textfile at some points where lines 246810 and so on had also dupes.
This is where my thoughts about this fixed string came up.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a few more lines of expected input (e.g. maybe 10-15 lines), add the expected output, make sure the example truly demonstrates your requirements, and describe your requirements in terms of the example you provide, not in terms of some other input file we can't see that apparently has thousands of lines (lines 13579 and 246810) or even 9+ lines ("line 1 and 9...").

Comment: _I hope this is as clear as it could be_: unfortunately not. You explain that if duplicates are found in lines 1 and 9 you want lines 9 and 10 to be deleted. But you also more or less explain that if duplicates are found in lines 13579 and 246810 you don't want to delete lines 246810 and 246811. Why? Is it a matter of number of lines separating the duplicates? If yes, what is the threshold above which you want to ignore the duplicates? If no, what is the reason for not deleting lines 246810 and 246811?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
fxStrBeg = index($0,fxStr) {
    tailOfLine = substr($0,fxStrBeg + length(fxStr) + 1)
    if ( seen[tailOfLine]++ ) {
        numLinesToSkip = 2
    }
}
numLinesToSkip > 0 {
    if ( numLinesToSkip-- > 0 ) {
        next
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -v fxStr='fixedstring' -f tst.awk file
somerandomtexthere fixedstring somepossibledupetext
line to also delete if dupe right above
...
```

but the example you provided is far from adequate to demonstrate your requirements (what should happen given "fixedstring" twice on a line, "fixedstring" on back-to-back lines, "fixedstring" as a substring of some lengthier string, "fixedstring" containing regexp metachars, what are the references to lines 13579 and 246810 about, where/what are lines 1 and 9, etc., etc.) so it's a guess.

I used many meaningfully-named variable names and generally lengthier than necessary code to try to make it clear what the code is doing. See [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for more information on how to idiomatically do tasks like this in general.

Comment: nice as always ++, thnx

Comment: You guys do the magic! I really had to gather some serious amount of brain cells to understand how to handle your snippet but it seems like it does what I really was craving for! :D
So after creating some kind of scriptfile based on your tst.awk, executing the awk command including the tst.awk basecode and fireing it on the targetfile I got my textfile cleaned from duplicated content but without leftover single lines. Randomly checked and everything seems to be on its position.

Before hitting the check mark I need to dive deeper in the results but seems really promising to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to delete duplicate lines:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' input.txt
```

or with perl

```
perl -lane 'print unless $seen{$F[0]}++' input.txt
```

or with sed

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/d; P; D' input.txt
```

**update**

according to your comment,you can use the `substr` function to extract the relevant portion of each line and by using the `NR` (record number) variable in `awk` you can specify the desired line numbers too!

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    start_line = 1  # Start line number
    skip_line = 2   # Skip every second line
    count = 1
}
{
    lines[NR] = $0
    if (NR > end_line) {
        end_line = NR
    }
}
END {
    for (i = start_line; i <= end_line; i++) {
        if (count % skip_line == 1) {
            fixed_string = "fixed starting point"
            text = substr(lines[i], index(lines[i], fixed_string) + length(fixed_string) + 1)
            if (text != "" && !seen[text]++) {
                print lines[i]
            }
        }
        count++
    }
}' input.txt
```

Comment: thx for sharing. tried that already. was my very first try.
due to fact that lines 13579 potentially could be dupe content but with slightly different text before that fixed string there would be then some leftover dupes.
only thing that could ensure getting rid of every dupe content is that fixed starting point i think. because dupes could have slightly different text before that fixed string but always the same text after that fixed string.

Comment: awk '!seen[$0]++' input.txt should be perfect if I could tell not to scan whole line but only after this fixed string as mentioned. because this string will only occur in lines 13579...

Comment: You need more than `!seen[$0]++` to also remove the subsequent line.

Comment: tested so many code in last two days. please dont blame me for beeing slightly confused. :)

Comment: is there a way to tell awk to only search in lines 13579 and skip checking lines 246810 and so on?
That should be enough but not really safe if somewhere in that text file is a deviation from the usual scheme.
Every 2nd line is related to the line above. But maybe there could be some missing files in origin files somehow in the future.

Comment: @diggidre Please edit your question to provide an adequate example that demonstrated your requirements and we can copy/paste to test on. I don't believe you actually want code to skip line 13579 but instead in your real input that line happens to have some characteristic that means you want us to skip it but the example in your question gives us no clue what that is about.

Comment: @Freeman just checked your code before your last edit without NR function and it deletes duplicated lines but there were many "forgotton" i will call them 246810 lines :)

The code after your last edit with NR function isnt really clear to me. If I could tell awk to skip every second line (246810...) then I would prevent deleting dupes in 246810 but also still end up with some leftovers. so this could be some kind of workaround but not ideal. thx for sharing your code anyways. Instead of restrict to start_line & end_line like you did how will this skip evry 2nd line for scanning?

Comment: I will work on a example and edit my origin post @EdMorton

Comment: sounds nice but assuming end line = 9 has to be the very last line number from origin file right? if so i have to say it varies and is not fixed. For testing purposes I changed value 9 to real last line number but the code only manipulates the file like list all lines 13579 and then list all lines 246810. So it separates all 246810 lines and list them right after all 13579 lines. ;)