# Is it possible to grab the last N lines of context from *each* grep match?

Tags: awk, grep

Consider the following input file:

```
FixedHeader
Body1
Body2
BodyX
BodyY
BodyZ

Unrelated text111
Unrelated text551
Unrelated text111
Unrelated text551

FixedHeader
Body3
Body4
BodyX
BodyY
BodyZ

Unrelated text111
Unrelated text551

FixedHeader
Body5
Body6
BodyA
BodyB
BodyZC
```

I can grep for `FixedHeader` and pull the five lines after it with the following command:

```
egrep -A5 "FixedHeader"
```

However, what I want to do is identify `FixedHeader` and always grab the line 5 lines after it, but NOT output any of the rest of the context. Expected output:

```
BodyZ
BodyZ
BodyZC
```

**Is there a way to output the line N lines down in the context of a grep match?**

I'm not attached to grep in particular, although one-liners are preferable if they exist.

Comment: @EdMorton I've added the expected output, as requested.
No, the input can have an arbitrary number of lines after the FixedHeader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with `awk`:

```
awk '/FixedHeader/ {target_line=NR + 5} NR==target_line' input.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In the style of the idioms posted at [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) you could do this:

```
$ awk 'c&&!--c; /FixedHeader/{c=5}' file
BodyZ
BodyZ
BodyZC
```

What the OP has in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77412358/1745001) is fine for this specific problem though, the above isn't any better other than being a bit easier to adapt to different requirements but then it's not as immediately obvious how it works either.

Alternatively, though, since you have empty-line separated paragraphs in your input you could just use awk in paragraph mode with fields separated by `\n` instead of any white space:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/^FixedHeader/{print $6}' file
BodyZ
BodyZ
BodyZC
```

The difference with that last one is that if there were fewer than 5 lines after `FixedHeader` it'd print an empty line whereas 2 solutions already discussed could print a line out of the next paragraph, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
FixedHeader
Body1
Body2

Unrelated text111
Unrelated text551
Unrelated text111
Unrelated text551
```

```
$ awk '/FixedHeader/ {target_line=NR + 5} NR==target_line' file
Unrelated text551
$
```

```
$ awk 'c&&!--c; /FixedHeader/{c=5}' file
Unrelated text551
$
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/^FixedHeader/{print $6}' file

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '$i = $. + 5 if /FixedHeader/;  print if $. == $i;' in_file
```

Alternatively, if the patterns you `grep` are spaced out more frequently than every 5 lines, use this solution (less memory-efficient, because it loads the entire file into memory):

```
perl -ne 'push @s, $_; push @i, ( $. - 1 ) if /FixedHeader/; END { @i = map { $i = $_ + 5; $i; } @i; print for @s[@i]; }' in_file
```

Prints:

```
BodyZ
BodyZ
BodyZC
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

Nested `sed` ranges can solve a lot of these problems, too.

```
$: sed -n '/^FixedHeader/,+5{         # on a header and the next five lines
             /^FixedHeader/,+4d       # ignore the header and the next FOUR lines
             p                        # print the desired line per header
           }' infile
BodyZ
BodyZ
BodyZC
```

...but Ed's paragraph-mode `awk` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441330/8656552) is your much better option for the reasons he gave.