# awk print n results of search in one line and add comma separation

Tags: awk

Please explain me how I should accomplish the following using `awk`:

I need to create a mirror of the 1st two `146G` drives on a raid controller. If i show the list of empty drives I get this result:

```
Smart Array P420 in Slot 5

unassigned

physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
```

For this example I put the list in a file `free-drives` and then create command. I want to get output like so:

```
drives=1I:1:1,1I:1:2
```

My 1st try is

```
drives=$(awk '/146 GB/ { printf $2"," ;}; END{print ;}' free-drives)
```

but that results in

```
1I:1:1,1I:1:2,2I:1:5,2I:1:6,
```

I couldn't find a proper way to get rid of the trailing comma so I used `sed` to get rid of that [1].

```
drives=$(awk '/146 GB/ { printf $2"," ;}; END{print ;}' free-drives|sed -e 's/,$//g')
```

Still we have 4 disks, I need two. So I tried some tips I've read in [5316572](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316572), like this one:

```
drives=$(awk 'a-->0;/146 GB/{ printf $2"," ;}{a=2}; END{print ;}' free-drives|sed -e 's?,$??g')
```

but this yields a complete mess.

So, what is the correct way of doing this with only one `awk` oneliner?

[1]: If you have any advise for me how to fix this: That would be great too ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one-liner should give what you want:

```
 awk '/146 GB/{x++;s=s?s","$2:$2}x==2{print s;exit}' free-drivers
```

with your input, it outputs:

```
1I:1:1,1I:1:2
```

I think you know how to assign it to variable, so I just skip that part.

Answer (score 0):

This should do that:

```
awk '/146 GB/{t=t $2 ","}; END{sub(/,$/, "", t); print t}' free-drives
```

Output:

```
1I:1:1,1I:1:2,2I:1:5,2I:1:6
```

Comment: Thanx Konsolebox, but that command seems not to do exactly what i want: when I test, the results looks like so:
    1I:1:11I:1:22I:1:52I:1:6