# grep - print next 10 lines if the line containing one word but not another in the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containing lines, like this:

```
some strings here class="batch2010" some more strings here click-here
<about 20-30lines here>
some strings here class="batch2006" some more strings here click-here
<about 20-30lines here>
some strings here class="NA" some more strings here click-here
<about 20-30lines here>
some strings here class="batch2010" some more strings here access-denied
<about 20-30lines here>
```

I want to print the line that contains:

`class="batch2010"`

but NOT:

`access-denied`

in the same line and then print the next 10 lines in the file.

Is there any other way, other than having to write a really long and complex shell script?

Comment: 1) what about line with access denied in the following line that are elligible ? 2) what about several elligible line in 10 following line of one occurance (print each separately or until the 10 last after last elligible in the block or only part until next 10 line and not a new occurence, ...) ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Chances that the line with access-denied will occur in the next 10 lines is none. So, it automatically does mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a solution:

```
awk 'lines>0 {print; --lines}
     /ass="batch2010"/ && !/access-denied/ {lines=10}' file
```

See output (not very relevant, as there are not many lines):

```
$ awk '(lines>0) {print; --lines} /ass="batch2010"/ && !/access-denied/ {lines=10}' a
some strings here class="batch2006" some more strings here click-here
some strings here class="NA" some more strings here click-here
some strings here class="batch2010" some more strings here access-denied
```

Its logic is based on [How to print 5 consecutive lines after a pattern in file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316718/1983854) adding the part in which we match `ass="batch2010"` and "unmatch" `access-denied`.

#### Test

```
$ seq 30 > a
$ awk 'lines>0 {print; --lines} /4/ && !/14/ {lines=10}' a
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

Comment: Why not just `awk 'lines>0 {print; --lines} /ass="batch2010"/ && !/access-denied/ {lines=10}' a`

Comment: You are very right, @Jotne, good one! Just updated accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Or just `awk 'lines-->0; /ass="batch2010"/ && !/access-denied/ {lines=10}' a`  :)

Comment: Well... that's a bit too much :D I prefer the code to be a bit auto-explanatory!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
< thefile grep -v 'access-denied' | grep -A10 'class="batch2010"'
```

Comment: Not very sure if this is exactly what the OP is asking for. What there is a line containing `access-denied` within the next 10 lines after `class="batch2010"`? Then, that line won't be printed while it should.

Comment: I agree. If the OP makes that case explicit, I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for yoyu (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/access-denied/b;/class="batch2010"/{:a;$!{N;s/\n/&/10;Ta};p}' file
```

Bail out if line contains  `access-denied` otherwise if line contains `class="batch2010"` read in the next 10 lines and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

This sed command should work
Sed in non-printing mode.
if it finds `denied`, breaks and jumps to end of sed statement.
If not looks for `2010` and prints the next 10 lines

```
sed -n '/denied/b;/2010/,+10p' file
```

Comment: This will miss `denied` lines within the 10 lines following `2010`.

Comment: @potong and why would that matter ?

Comment: The question says "grep - print next 10 lines if the line containing one word but not another in the same line" it does not say anything about filtering those 10 lines.

Comment: But you want to skip denied lines anyway ?