# Print lines after a pattern in several files

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file with the same pattern several times.
Something like:

```
   time
   12:00
   12:32
   23:22
   time
   10:32
   1:32
   15:45
```

I want to print the lines after the pattern, in the example `time`
in several files. The number of lines after the pattern is constant.
I found I can get the first part of my question with `awk '/time/ {x=NR+3;next}(NR<=x){print}' filename`
But I have no idea how to output each chunk into different files.

**EDIT**

My files are a bit more complex than my original question.
They have the following format.

```
4
gen
 C        -4.141000       -0.098000        0.773000
 H        -4.528000       -0.437000       -0.197000
 H        -4.267000        0.997000        0.808000
 H        -4.777000       -0.521000        1.563000
 4
 gen
 C        -4.414000       -0.398000        4.773000
 H        -4.382000       -0.455000       -4.197000
 H        -4.267000        0.973000        2.808000
 H        -4.333000       -0.000000        1.636000
```

I want to print the lines after

```
  4
  gen
```

**EDIT 2**

My expected output is `x` files `x=# pattern`.
From my second example, I want two files:

```
 C        -4.141000       -0.098000        0.773000
 H        -4.528000       -0.437000       -0.197000
 H        -4.267000        0.997000        0.808000
 H        -4.777000       -0.521000        1.563000
```

and

```
 C        -4.414000       -0.398000        4.773000
 H        -4.382000       -0.455000       -4.197000
 H        -4.267000        0.973000        2.808000
 H        -4.333000       -0.000000        1.636000
```

Comment: Crossposting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266133/74329

Comment: @Cyrus I think that you gave the link to this question.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein no, he didn't. click on it to see.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '/time/{close(out); out="output" ++i; next} {print > out}' file
```

This awk command creates a variable `out` based on a fixed prefix `output` and an incrementing counter `i` which gets incremented every time we get a line `time`. All subsequent lines are redirected to this output file. Is is a good practice to close these file handles to avoid memory leak.

**PS:** If you want `time` line also in output then remove `next` in above command.

Comment: I didn't really get. Actually I want each chunk into a different file.

Comment: It is indeed creating a different file for each chunk. Did you test it? It is creating output file with the names as `output1`, `output2`, `output3` etc

Comment: thanks @anubhava for the example file I gave it really worked. My problem is a bit more complex though. I edited my question.

Comment: ok can you also include new expected output by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

The revised "4/gen" requirements are somewhat ambiguous but the following script (which is just a variant of @anubhava's) conforms with those that are given and can easily be modified to deal with various edge cases:

```
awk '
  /^ *4 *$/ {close(out); out=0; next}
  /^ *gen *$/ && out==0 {out = "output." ++i; next}
  out {print > out} '
```

Answer (score -1):

I found another answer from anubhava  here [How to print 5 consecutive lines after a pattern in file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316572/how-to-print-5-consecutive-lines-after-a-pattern-in-file-using-awk)
and with head and for loop I solved my problem:
`for i in {1..23}; do grep -A25 "gen" allTemp | tail -n 25 > xyz$i; head -n -27 allTemp > allTemp2; cp allTemp2 allTemp; done`

I know that file `allTemp` has `23` occurrences of `gen`.
Head will remove the lines I printed to `xyzi` as well as the two lines I don't want and it will output a new file to `allTemp2`