# syntax error searching pattern and print next 5 lines using awk command in a SINGLE line

Tags: awk, syntax

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316572/how-to-print-5-consecutive-lines-after-a-pattern-in-file-using-awk) has the answer to getting 5 lines after pattern. I am trying my own method with this command:

`awk 'BEGIN{count=0} { /pattern/{count=5;next}; if(count>0){print; --count;} }' inputFile`

but this gives me syntax error.

Comment: `/pattern/` can't be used like this inside of curly braces. You can replace it with `if ($0 ~ /pattern/)`.

Comment: This should do what you want : `awk '/pattern/{count=5;next}(count>0){print; --count}`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for how to really do this.

Comment: @BenjaminW. right but you can just write `if (/pattern/)`, no need to add`$0 ~` as that's the default. Also, the OP doesn't need any `if` statements at all - just get rid of the surrounding `{` and `}` to use awks condition/action syntax.