# AIX Find 2 lines below the search String

Tags: aix

I am trying to come up with a script or a command to find the line that is 2 lines below a search parameter in AIX. Please help with the correct command syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this `awk ' /pattern/ { printf "%s", before2; } { before2= before1; before1= $0 "\n"; }`

Comment: Or maybe something like `awk '/pattern/ {next,next,print}'`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer based on the answer given here: [How to print 5 consecutive lines after a pattern in file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316572/how-to-print-5-consecutive-lines-after-a-pattern-in-file-using-awk)

```
awk '/pattern/ {print $0; {getline;getline; print}}' filename
```

Comment: What will you get if the pattern occurs in three consecutive lines?